# Kswapd using >90% CPU. What is it doing?

Tags: kernel, swap, cpu-usage

I have run GNU/Linux since 0.99, and it is only in the most recent years that I have seen `kswapd` use any serious CPU-time.

In ye olde days the swapsystem would be waiting for the disk and hardly use any CPU time while waiting for the disk to respond.

What changed, so that `kswapd` now happily eats almost a full core?

What is `kswapd` doing that is so CPU heavy?

Comment: Related reading: https://askubuntu.com/a/530661/436624

Answer (score 0):

One of my systems uses zswap, and that can explain why `kswapd` uses CPU on that system: It compresses RAM, which obviously will take serious CPU time. I have see it use 800% CPU on that.

But I have the feeling this is not the only thing that costs serious CPU time.

Comment: Why does anyone have swap _enabled_ these days when RAM is so _affordable_?

Comment: An upgrade from 0.5T to 1T would on my R815-server costs around 2500 USD. I paid less than 1000 USD for the full 0.5T server. The server does not support more than 1T RAM, so I will be hitting that limit anyway; not all the time but now and then. My laptop is even worse: It does not even support 0.5T, so it would be impossible to install 0.5T in it. Thus zswap + swap seems to be the only option.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32857/is-swap-an-anachronism